# Enrollment Profile fails to install in Apple Configurator

Tags: mac-osx-server, apple

I'm trying to enroll devices to the Profile Manager via the Apple Configurator. Everything works out just fine except the Enrollment Profile. It always fails with error code 4001 (MCIntallationErrorDomain) and -1001 (NSURLErrorDomain). I followed the steps in this page: Apple Configurator: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201334 - Apple Support but the Enrollment Profile just won't install. Anyone have any thoughts or suggestions I could try? I'm at my wits end here.

Found this post, but not working answer has been provided. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590367/enrollment-profile-wont-install-apple-configurator-1-5-ota-ios7-1

Answer (score 1):

NSURLErrorDomain -1001 is a connection timed out error:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes

Your device is apparently unable to connect to the Profile Manager server over its wifi.

Try visiting the server directly in Safari by entering a URL like https://myserver.local/mydevices and make sure it loads there.

Also, it may be more reliable to use the auto-enrollment URL under Prepare > Setup > Enrollment in Configurator, rather than pushing profiles, because the device is guaranteed to have joined Wi-Fi when the user later accepts the MDM configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! -- If I use the auto-enrollment through the configurator, then that means I need to be using DEP, which we're not. -- Also, the enrollment profile needs to use wifi despite the fact that it's hooked directly into the server?

Comment: @fischgeek How is it hooked to the server? If it's a USB connection, that won't provide a network connection (which enrollment needs).

Comment: @GordonDavisson - Thank you. That makes sense. I have my network guys looking into this.